# Bold paragraph symbol in redefined paragraph command

Tags: macros, symbols

I have redefined the paragraph command, so that a paragraph symbol is pronted along with the number.

```
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\S \arabic{paragraph}}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\large\bfseries\filright}{\theparagraph\quad}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pc}{*1}{-0.5ex}[0pc]
\setcounter{paragraph}{0}
```

This works fine, but I want the paragraph symbol to be bold (just like the number and text). 
Normally I could just use \textbf{\S}, but if I do this in the above example, this has no effect.

Why does the symbol not become bold, and how will it become bold?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Add `\usepackage{textcomp}` to your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the standard setting (and so the OT1 font encoding), the paragraph symbol ¶ is taken from a math font, so it's not available in boldface unless `\boldmath` is issued, but it would be wrong when referencing.

The best solution is to load also the TS1 encoding with

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

so the symbol will be taken from a specialized font that respects the font attributes.